# Use of 'this' pointer to delete

Tags: c++, this, delete-operator

I'm working on a project for school.
It simulates students buying soda from a vending machine.
There is a class called Card that is a member in the class Student.
That is,

Every student has a card, which makes sense.

```
class Student {
public:
    Student( Office &cardOffice );
    ~Student();
    bool action();
    private:
    Office* studentOffice;          // stores cardoffice.
    Card* card;                 // stores card
};
```

A student's card is created via a call to the studentOffice.create() function. That function returns a card.

```
Card* Office::create( int id, int money ) {
    Card* card = new Card();
    card->id = id;
    card->amount = money;
    return card;
}
```

Students call a function in the class VendingMachine called action() to buy food. The buy function in VendingMachine returns a type enumeration from the Status enum in the VendingMachine class.

There is a prng, generating a random number from 0 - 9. The assignment says that there is a 1 in 10 chance of the student's card being destroyed. And he/she will obtain a new one the next time student.action() is called.

```
VendingMachine::Status VendingMachine::buy(Card* &card)
{
    if(prng(9) == 0) // generates number from 0-9
    {
        delete card;
    }
    return status;
}
```

Originally, I was thinking to check in the student's action() routine to see if the card is NULL, (if it was deleted), and create a new one if that happens. However, I know the code gets to the delete card portion, but it fails when checking that the card is NULL. So that must mean the card is not null, which means the delete didn't work.

But I also noticed that the card that is passed in is of type

```
Card* &card
```

I was then thinking of using a call with the "this" pointer as I know the student is what called this routine and "this" will point to the object that called it according to:

It points to the object for which the member function is called.
from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0dddwwd(v=vs.80).aspx

However, if I do:

```
if(prng(9) == 0)
{
    delete this->card;
}
```

it gives me this error when running my makefile:

> error: class VendingMachine has no member named card

Which is true, it doesn't. Is the compiler assuming that a VendingMachine will call this method? Because the student does.

1. Maybe I should add a student to every vending machine and delete the card from that member instead? I would strongly prefer not doing this, as there are multiple students and that would mean I need to store them all if they are assigned to this vending machine. Although, if it comes down to it, I could do it this way.
2. If the delete card happened, but the card is not NULL, what exactly went down when I deleted the card?
3. How would I go about deleting the card?

Thanks!

EDIT: After applying the changes, the code is now:

```
if(prng(9) == 0)
{
    cout << "Destroying card" << endl;
    delete card;
    card = NULL;
    cout << "Card Destroyed" << endl;
    }
```

Unfortunately, I get a segfault and that is probably because I'm accessing a destroyed card that doesn't exist. Because Destroying card and Card Destroyed is displayed,

But the cout I have in this call is not showing up:

```
    if(card == NULL)
    {
        cout << "CARD DESTROYEDADJIWJDOQIODJWDIOJWQODWODIQODJWJOWDW" << endl;
        card = studentOffice->create(id, 5);
    }
```

So apparently the card is still not NULL? This is weird.

EDIT2: I think I know where the problem is, and why there's a segfault. Working on it right now.

EDIT3: Solved by rearranging the order on the calls that used card when it was destroyed.

Comment: Calling `delete` does not make a pointer NULL. This needs to be done explicitly.

Comment: You might want to consider having a "destroyed" flag in the Card class, rather than deleting the Card object. This would prevent a load of `if NULL` tests and the need to pass pointer references around.

Comment: @Roddy: I think one of the points of this assignment is to teach students how to pass pointer references correctly.

Comment: @Justinᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ We were given the structure of the assignment. That is, the functions we're allowed to have, and so on. The passing in was the assignment and we were not allowed to change that. :)

Comment: Would be better **not** to use pointers. Pass a `Card value` around rather than a `Card pointer`. Pointers have no ownership semantics and thus it is not clear who is responsible for deleting them and thus are not used (RAW like that) much in modern C++. When you have a pointer it is usually wrapped inside a smart pointer. But this case is simple enough that you don't even need a pointer.

Comment: Also Note: If your class contains pointers it should obey the rule of three (your code does not). This will lead to problems down the road and you should fix it. Also having a class with more than one pointer is exceptionally hard to do correctly (and be exception safe). It is unusual for a class to have more than one `owned` pointer you should look at smart pointers to solve the problem (or maybe office is really just a reference (not a pointer).

Comment: @Justinᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ - or, why *not* to pass pointer references around!

Comment: @Roddy: Indeed. I'm certainly of the opinion that C++ has much better mechanisms for doing things like this *without* using pointers, though when it comes to straight C you'd be limiting yourself by trying to avoid pointers entirely. Still, when pointers ***are*** involved I do try to avoid passing them by reference. Thanks for the mention, I'd probably not have seen Loki's comments without yours :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In method `buy` you should delete the pointer and set it to `NULL` (`delete` does not automatically set the pointer to `NULL`):

```
VendingMachine::Status VendingMachine::buy(Card* &card)
{
    if(prng(9) == 0) // generates number from 0-9
    {
        delete card;
        card = NULL;
    }
    return status;
}
```

That is the reason why the pointer is passed by reference (so you can assign `NULL` to the original pointer and not a copy of it).

Besides that, `this->card` does not compile, since `card` belongs to class `Student`, not to  `VendingMachine`. From `VendingMachine`'s perspective, it is just a parameter in method `buy`.

Comment: Ahh, I will try that. Thank you so much. What is the difference between

Passing in Card* &card and just Card card? Don't the pointer and reference cancel out in this case? Also, I originally just set the card to NULL, and did not have the delete card; line there. Was that wrong as well? If so, why?

Comment: @tf.rz You can pass the pointer as a reference (`Card*& card`) or as a value (`Card* card`). In the second case, a copy of the pointer is passed, so you would not modify the original pointer (the one used to call `buy` method). If you use a reference, there is no copy, so the original pointer is set to `NULL`.

Comment: Ah thank you for the explanation. Please see the edit. I have made the changes and get a segfault, but the two lines in the new conditional check show up. However, the check for the card in student.action() is not displayed. The card is somehow still not NULL!

Comment: @tf.rz You would need to post the code where `buy` method is called, so we can see where the problem might be. But it seems you are on the right track, so you might have it solved by now :)

Comment: I pasted the code for you! Still think I'm on to something. Trying out new stuff as we speak. :)

Answer (score 2):

When you call `delete` there is nothing to say that the pointer you called it on gets set to `NULL`. If you want to make sure it is NULL after a delete, you should do it yourself after you delete it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @betabandido's answer, you can always define a delete method in a macro to do this for you.

```
#define DELETE(ptr) ( delete ptr; ptr = NULL;)
```

Though admittedly, this is almost always a bad idea, and especially while you are in school, you should just get into the habit of setting your pointers back to NULL after deleting them.

Also, this can lead you into a false sense of security:

```
void MethodDeleteThis(void* item)
{
   delete item;
   item = NULL;
}
```

Does not really fix the issue, because item is a COPY of whatever pointer was passed. So, while delete may have freed the object pointed to by item, setting the pointer to NULL will not change the value of the pointer passed to the method to NULL. The only way around this is to take double pointers or to pass the pointer by reference--something that often seems odd and out of place. I have seen gobject and gstreamer do this however.

Many libraries, I have noticed, always return the pointer if there is any allocation or deallocation so that you can retrieve and test the value more reliably.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! +1 I think habits right now are the most important thing to develop. Good ones, that is. Thank you for the tips. I followed what you and @betabandido suggested

Comment: @tf.rz: Setting pointers to NULL is usually  a bad idea as they hide other more serious logic problems in your code. It just happens in "this" case that it is what you need. In general it is not the best solution. It is best to delete in destructors at which point the pointer falls out of any scope and is not used.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, any time you `delete` a pointer you should also set it to `NULL` immediately afterward. Don't use a macro, get in the habit of doing this.

Now, attempting to put on my best practices hat:

I've always found it more useful to pass double pointers when doing this sort of thing, rather than passing a pointer by reference:

```
VendingMachine::Status VendingMachine::buy(Card** card) {
    // ...
    if (NULL == *card) {
        delete *card;
        *card = NULL;
    }
```

This forces you to treat the pointer a bit differently in the code, but the benefit is that it's more obvious that you're manipulating a pointer, and it eliminates ambiguity in your method calls:

```
  vend.buy(card);  // Pointer reference
  vend.buy(&card); // Pointer to pointer
```

With the second call, you know just by looking at it that the method can and probably will modify the value of `card`.

Comment: I see your point, and as you say, it makes more obvious the fact that you want to modify something at the calling place (instead than at the method/function definition). But if you apply this everywhere, you would just stop using references, right? Not sure, if that is a good idea...

Comment: Thank you for the useful information, it's an interesting approach, but unfortunately us students are restrained in how we implement our code. The assignment essentially has header files that define what parameters are passed in. We can't change that. We're also not allowed to add any more public members or routines. Really unrealistic, but it is.. school work. ;)

Comment: @betabandido: According to the C++ FAQ, "use reference wherever you can, and pointers wherever you must." I happen to disagree with that blanket statement for the reasons outlined, but references certainly have their place. I learned on ANSI C so pointers come naturally to me. In the real world you're going to encounter a metric ass-ton of pointers when working with other peoples' code, so being familiar with all approaches is best.

Comment: @tf.rz: I understand that your assignments are constrained and they have a purpose for teaching, and you should certainly complete the assignment in whatever way the professor has asked. My point was to show you an alternate approach, and give you something more to think on.